# How to reverse each half of a doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to reverse each half of a doubly linked list, lets assume the list is even and sorting doesn't matter.

lets say I have this input,
the list can have any even number of elements.

1 <=> 5 <=> 8 <=> 3 <=> 2 <=> 10

This is the expected output

8 <=> 5 <=> 1 <=> 10 <=> 2 <=> 3

I found the length of the list, to find the middle position, then I tried using a counter to go through each half,however, I feel lost once I start doing lots of while loops. I know how to reverse the whole list but I am stuck further. 
Does anyone have any ideas?

```
template <class T>
void DoubyLinkedList<T>:: ReverseFunction() {

node<T> *ptr = head;

//find length of list

int length = 0;
while (ptr!=NULL) {
ptr = ptr->next;
length++;
}

ptr = head;

int c = 1;
//This code reverses the whole list 
while (ptr != NULL ) {

    node<T> *tmp = ptr->next;

    ptr->next = ptr->prev;

    ptr->prev = tmp;
}

    if (tmp == NULL) {

        tail = head;
        head = ptr;

    }
    ptr = tmp;

}

}
```

Comment: if its a double link list I would assume it should have pointer to both head and a tail. just a thought but, can't you just start on both ends till you meet in the middle and start reversing on both directions once you got to the middle. it might be better than trying to loop through the entire list just to find it's the size and restarting the loop.

Comment: @Yucel_K thanks for your comment!, I actually tried this, but I couldn’t get it to work, I’ll work on it again and add it to the question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would express the idea in terms of [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Basically, cut from head and tail one element, create two new lists and then merge them. All operations are O(1).

```
std::list<int> reverseHalfs(std::list<int> &l) {
    assert((l.size() % 2) == 0);
    std::list<int> newHead;
    std::list<int> newTail;
    while (l.size() > 1) {
        newHead.push_front(l.front());
        newTail.push_back(l.back());
        l.pop_front();
        l.pop_back();
    }
    newHead.splice(end(newHead), newTail);
    return newHead;   
}
```

Comment: while i understand why it's useful to make use of std::list, I am under the impression that using std list may not be an option considering how the list class is looking. perhaps its a course work that tries to teach how the link lists work internally.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! As this is a part of an assignment I can’t rely on library but I’ll keep this method in mind for the future

Comment: I used this just to express the idea how to solve the reversion problem, replace std::list with your own implementation and all will work. std::list has a nice design in terms of API. You can provide same interface for your own list.

Comment: I’m having trouble in implementing the last line newhead.splice I know I need to use a loop to add elements from one list to another, I need to make a pointer that points to the newhead’s tail? and then add the elements of the other list as add to head to newhead list? Am I saying something right?

Comment: Or is there no need for loops and can I just link them together? newhead.tail->next = newtail.head and newtail.head->prev = newhead->tail ? Thanks in advance

Comment: As I mentioned before, all operations are O(1). It means no loops here, just append one list to the end of another.

Comment: I used an append function I made previously instead, and all worked fine, very neat! Thanks much!